# How to prevent component from being re-rendered unnecessarily

Tags: reactjs

I'll start with the code. I have a stateless functional component that resembles this

```
export const Edit Topic = (_title, _text) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(_title)
    const [text, setText] = useState(_text)

    return (
      <>
         <InputText props={{ fieldName:"Title:", value:title, setValue:setTitle, placeHolder:"Topic Title"}}/>
         <InputTextArea props={{ fieldName:"Markdown Text:", text, setText }}/>
         <PreviewBox text={text}/>
      </>
   )
}
```

I have `PreviewBox` when it's on, page rendering takes a bit longer because `text` can be quite long. `PreviewBox` needs to re-render each time I change text in `InputTextArea` and that's fine.

The problem I'm having is when I change the value of `title` it's also updating `<PreviewBox/>` which is undesired.

How can I make sure that `<PreviewBox/>` only updates when `text` changes and not when `title` changes?

The reason why I believe the re-rendering is occuring is because if I toggle off `PreviewBox`, there's no lag in when updating `title` but when `PreviewBox` is visible the updating the `title` lags.

---

```
import style from "../styles/CreateTopic.module.css"
import { Component } from "react"
import Markdown from "./Markdown";

export class PreviewBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isShow: true
        }
    }

    toggleShow = () => {
        console.log("begin isShow", this.state)
        this.setState(state => ({ isShow: !state.isShow}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className={style.wrptoggle}>
                        <button className={style.btn} onClick={this.toggleShow}>Preview</button>
                </div>

                {this.state.isShow ?
                    <div className={style.wrppreviewbox}>
                        <div className={style.previewbox}>
                            <Markdown text={this.props.text}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    : null}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Since the above also contains `<Markdown/>` here's that component:

```
import remarkMath from "remark-math";
import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";

const Markdown = ({text}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown
        remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
        rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
        children={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Markdown;
```

Comment: This is an example of a "stateful" component. This is how React components work, when they rerender they will rerender their entire sub-tree. What or how are you determining the rerendering?

Comment: Okay, so if I'm understanding correctly, I'd need to put the Title in separate component in order to keep the rendering separate. This page is for editting a document so how would I access the title information on submission if I made them separate?

Comment: @DrewReese if you could point me to a resource, twould be much appreciated

Comment: What is `PreviewBox` doing when it's rendered? Can you share that component in your question?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any complexity in `PreviewBox` that would cause any rendering delay so I might assume it's the `Markdown` component that may take some time "working" when it's rerendered since you say "toggle off `PreviewBox`, there's no lag in when updating `title`".

## Solution

You can use the [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) Higher Order Component to decorate the `Markdown` component and provide a custom `areEqual` props compare function.

```
import { memo } from 'react';
import remarkMath from "remark-math";
import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";

const Markdown = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown
        remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
        rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
        children={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default memo(Markdown);
```

> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props
> object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide
> a custom comparison function as the second argument.

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.text === nextProps.text;
};
 
export default memo(Markdown, areEqual);
```